# MongoDB with Java driver - Adding a new set to a nested array using $addToSet and updateOne

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

I have a collection with an entry that looks like the below.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57f6021caa3e1d3ee099af0d"),
"user" : "JBL123",
"name" : "Joe Bloggs",
"monthly_activity" : [
    {
        "month" : "September2016",
        "status" : "active",
        "daily_stats" : [
            {
                "date" : "27/SEP/2016",
                "stats" : [ 
                    {
                        "category":
                        "stat1":
                        "stat2":
                    },
                    {
                        "category":
                        "stat1":
                        "stat2":
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "date" : "28/SEP/2016",
                "stats" : [ 
                    {
                        "category": ...
                        "stat1": ...
                        "stat2": ...
                    },
                    {
                        "category": ...
                        "stat1": ...
                        "stat2": ...
                    }
                ]
            },
        ],
        "extra_fields": ....
    }
]
}
```

I want to insert stats for a new category on a specified date.

I've tried the below

```
mdb.getCollection("users").updateOne(new Document("user", "JBL123").append("monthly_activity.daily_stats.date", "27/SEP/2016"),
    new Document("$addToSet", (new Document("monthly_activity.daily_stats.$.stats",
        new Document("category",cat)
            .append("stat1", s1)
            .append("stat2", s2)))));
```

But it doesn't like using dot notation to access the subarray of an array. I get the following error...

> > Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: can't append to array using string field name [daily_stats]

Is this possible from a single update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`monthly_activity` is an array, so you need to use positional value/operator refer an element.

To identify the update field, you can use the positional operator **`$`** only once , even if the field is nested within arrays ([a current limitation](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831)). That would require you to know the position of the other arrays elements in the hierarchy. In this case, you will need to know the position of either `monthly_activity` or `daily_stats`.

If you have the position of the `monthly_activity` element (say 0), then you update field can be identified by `monthly_activity.0.daily_stats.$.stats`.

> The positional $ operator cannot be used for queries which traverse
>   more than one array, such as queries that traverse arrays nested
>   within other arrays, because the replacement for the $ placeholder is
>   a single value.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get that position? Ideally I would be searching monthly_activity for where month="September2016" and using that as the pointer, but can this be incorporated into the original filter?

Comment: something like `mdb.getCollection("users").updateOne(new Document("user", "JBL123").append("monthly_activity.daily_stats.date", "27/SEP/2016").append("monthly_activity.month","September2016",
    new Document("$addToSet", (new Document("monthly_activity.$.daily_stats.$.stats",
        new Document("category",cat)
            .append("stat1", s1)
            .append("stat2", s2)))));`

Comment: @bw12345 Updated my answer.